# Set trace id/span id to actual correlation-id for tracing requests using OpenTelemetry for c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, open-telemetry

Currently, we are integrating OpenTelemetry in our asp.net core solution and we are using `x-correlatin-id` header for tracing requests. Is it possible to set the current trace_id or span_id to the correlation id, to trace multiple requests, that belong together?

I've tried solving the problem by writing a custom processor, but the context information are only available for getting ids, not setting.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occured because

```
.AddHttpClientInstrumentation(o =>
{
    o.RecordException = true;
});
```

was missing when adding tracing.

**EDIT**

In my original implemantion I only used `.AddHttpClientInstrumentation()` and the part with `o.RecordException = true;` was missing.

Comment: Can you clarify if "the whole block" was missing, or just "RecordException = true" was missing? I'm assuming it's the former but just wanted to be sure.

Comment: yes, that was just missing

Comment: Hmm... you realize that your response still doesn't clarify it right? My question was "what exactly was missing", was the whole block you posted, or just the assignment inside it? I'm asking this specifically because the correct answer to your problem could just as well be "I missed `AddHttpClientInstrumentation()`", and the `RecordException` part is just noise that could confuse/mislead other people looking for the same answer. If you could clarify that, that would be great.

Comment: @julealgon better now?

Comment: Much better, thanks for the update.